# Bits Required to Store Values

Tags: binary, bit

How many bits are required to store three different values?
My guess is 8 times 3 = 24 bits.
I'm confused because I learned in class that a 8-bit byte can only hold a value between 0 and 255. Does this mean to store a value above 255 we need more than 8 bits?

Comment: How did you arrive at your guess?

Comment: "Does this mean to store a value above 255 we need more than 8 bits?" - yes, exactly. But from this observation, you already know that you need much fewer than 24 bits to store 3 values.

Answer (score 2):

A bit is either 0 or 1. So it can store 2 values.

Two bits can store 2*2 values, 4.

Three bits can store 2*2*2 values, 8.

And so on.

So to store 3 values, you need at least two bits.

You need more than 8 bits to store more than 256 values, yes, because 2^8 is 256.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: **two digits**.

In any number base system, the number of values that can be held by a single digit is equal to the base number, so for the regular base-10 number system, that would be 10 (0 through 9). To hold higher numbers, you give yourself more digits: this would be the ones place, tens place, hundreds place, etc you learned in school.

Once you start giving yourself more digits, then it's just a matter of combinations: in a two-digit base-10 number, how many combinations are there? 00 through 99, so 100; with three digits, 000 through 999, so 1000.

The name `bit` is nothing more than the special name given to the digit in base-2 (otherwise known as binary). It can hold exactly two values, 0 and 1. To get more, you'd have to give yourself another digit, e.g., the ones place, the twos place. And even more digits: the fours place, the eights place, etc. Again, it's nothing but combinatory math. Two base-2 digits (or binary digits, or `bit`s) can hold values 00 through 11, so 4; with three bits 00 through 111, so 8; with four bits 00 through 1111, so 16; with eight (a byte) 00000000 through 11111111, so 256.

So, in order to hold three values - e.g., 0 1 and 2 base-10 - you'd need **two digits**: 00 01 and 10 binary.